# What are ways to export data from tables in SAS DI?

Tags: sas, export-to-csv, sas-dis

I am very new to SAS and I have some tables in SAS DI under inventory which I need to export to text file, what are the easy to do this? Can I somehow create a program in SAS EG to display the data in there then export?

Answer (score 2):

In SAS Data Integration Studio:

You can either use a `File Writer` or `User Written Code` transformations to export the table to a file. If you are using `User Written Code` just use a `proc export` Example [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Management/Enhancing-CSV-file-output-to-Excel-w-user-written-code-in-DI/td-p/120523) and DI Studio documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etlug/67323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etlugwhatsnew49.htm).

In SAS Enterprise Guide:

Navigate in the SAS Folder to where your table is saved and double click to open the table, then you will see in the top right the option to export/send to excel.  Or you can write a `proc export` in a program (file-New- Program)